# Memset struct pointer causing null check failure

Tags: c, struct

I have a struct defined, and a function which takes in the struct pointer and fills in the relevant information, while doing a null check in the beginning.

**Rough example:**

```
typedef struct
{
  int field;
} myStruct;

void myFunc(myStruct *ptr)
{
  if(ptr == NULL)
  {
     printf("Pointer is null!");
  }
  // rest of code
}

int main()
{
  myStruct *ptr = NULL; // tried both *ptr; and *ptr = NULL;
  memset(&ptr, 0, sizeof(ptr));
  myFunc(ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

This program is just an example of what I did, and the outcome is that it **fails** the NULL check.

Any idea where it might be wrong? Maybe the memset is not right?

Comment: `NULL` isn't necessarily all bits zero..

Comment: Do you have an `else` or `return` or something after that `printf`, or just allow the program to continue into the rest of `myFunc` after determining that the pointer is null?

Comment: What actually happens? What's the "failure"? From this question I can't tell if the message is printed or not and whether you expect that to happen or not.

Comment: This example is not meant to compile/run. Hope you didn't really intend on trying to make this run. I just want to show the structure of what I did. I've added what happens as a result.

Comment: But we very much like things we can actually compile and run.  See [mcve].  If you try to give a rough idea, it's often (as here!) not enough information to actually determine what your issue is.

Comment: Okay, you win. To be fair, this code compiles and runs.

Comment: By "fails the null check", do you mean that it does print "Pointer is null", or that it does not print that?

Comment: It prints the message.

Comment: I don't understand the question then , why do you think the message should not be printed?

Comment: What is your platform?

Comment: What output do you get _exactly_? What does `printf("%p\n", NULL);` print on your platform? The answer depends on this.

Answer (score 0):

`ptr` has the value `NULL`, so it's not pointing to anything.  You need to assign the pointer to valid memory to be able to dereference it.

You should allocate memory for it first.

```
myStruct *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
myFunc(ptr);
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. I'm still getiing "Pointer is null!". Do you have an online IDE link?

Comment: @user3717271 Did you remove the `memset`?

Comment: Oh, right. My bad. It works, but is there a way to do it with memset and without malloc?

Comment: @user3717271 You would need to create an instance of the struct instead of a pointer, i.e. `myStruct instance`, then pass its address to `memset` and `myFunc`.

Answer (score 0):

The output of your program should be `Pointer is null!` on most platforms.

Explanation:

```
// setting ptr to NULL
myStruct *ptr = NULL;       // declaring and initializing ptr to NULL, this is obvious
```

Following is more subtle:

```
memset(&ptr, 0, sizeof(ptr));
```

This sets the `sizeof(ptr)` bytes at the address where `ptr` is stored to 0 which this is actually equivalent to `ptr = 0;`.

Now on most platform `NULL` is defined as `(void*)0`and therefore `ptr = NULL` is equivalent to `ptr = NULL` on those platforms.

Demonstration: http://ideone.com/SwxaKv

Short answer: remove `memset(&ptr, 0, sizeof(ptr));`